# issue with jQuery inside Drupal block

Tags: jquery, drupal, block

I need a quick fix on my website and since I am running out of time I need a quick solution.

I need to modify a css property when the screen width is between 959 and 768. To do this I created a block with the following content (NOTE: this is just a try to check the code):

```
<h1 class="prova"> ciao </h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

jQuery(document).ready( function () {
                 if ( jQuery(window).width() < 959 && jQuery(window).width() > 768 ) {
                            jQuery("h1.prova").css( "border", "3px solid red" );
                            jQuery("h1.prova").addClass( "testclass");
                };
});
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

The code above works but just when I load the page. In other words, if the browser width is 800px and I refresh the page, the CIAO h1 tag will have the new class and the border. Now if I re-size the window nothing won't happen. And if I refresh it after the re-sizing it will do what expected.

Most likely I am missing something very stupid, can you help me fix it please?

Thank you, 
guidout

## UPDATE:

Ok now I got a new problem :)

Thanks to the suggestion below I got the following to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
                 if ( jQuery(window).width() < 959 && jQuery(window).width() > 768 ) {
                            jQuery("#main-navigation ul li a").css( "padding-right", "14px" );
                            jQuery(".downarrowclass").css( "right", "6px" );
                };
                 if ( jQuery(window).width() > 959 || jQuery(window).width() < 768 ) {
                            jQuery("#main-navigation ul li a").css( "padding-right", "23px" );
                };
});
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

BUT if I refresh the page and the window is in between 959 and 768, the css are not applied. (of course). As soon as I re-size the window it works.
So I added the following:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
                 if ( jQuery(window).width() < 959 && jQuery(window).width() > 768 ) {
                            jQuery("#main-navigation ul li a").css( "padding-right", "14px" );
                            jQuery(".downarrowclass").css( "right", "6px" );
                };
                 if ( jQuery(window).width() > 959 || jQuery(window).width() < 768 ) {
                            jQuery("#main-navigation ul li a").css( "padding-right", "23px" );
                };
});
```

Not working...any suggestions?

Thanks,
Guido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from the docs: [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
 $( window ).resize(function() {
    //put your function here
 });
```

Also you can use .on('resize') which is the same.

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qM74N/3/).

Comment: not working. or better, working but same problem. I need to refresh to get the tag updated

Comment: you should check the code againg and try to use .on('resize'). I've created the fiddle 4u, check the link above

Comment: thanks for the help Prosto Trader, but still not working. Tried both ways. I do believe it is not a jQuery problem but it is how drupal handles the injection of jQuery code within a block.

Comment: Prosto Trader it worked. Many thanks. That was my fault, I was adding the border at a specific width but I never remove it so of course it will stay even if I bring the window width back to the original size. Adding another if statement it works. Thanks again